# Numerical issues in scipy's Savitzky Golay filter coefficients for large polynomial order

Tags: matlab, filter-design, scipy, least-squares

Consider the design of a Savitzky-Golay filter of window length 101 and (high) polynomial order 20.  Using scipy version 1.10.1, the filter coefficients can be obtained in python as:

```
from scipy import signal
h = signal.savgol_coeffs(window_length=101, polyorder=20)
```

leading to

[image]

For reference, in Matlab r2022b

```
order=20; framelen=101; b = sgolay(order,framelen); h = b((framelen+1)/2,:);
```

gives
[image]

which looks more reasonable.  For lower order polynomials, the results coincide much more closely.

It looks like scipy's implementation solves a least squares problem where the design matrix is computed as:

```
 order = np.arange(polyorder + 1).reshape(-1, 1)
 A = x ** order
```

leading to a condition number > 1e29!

Is there some other way to get these coefficients in python?

Comment: Do you need to compute these at run-time? If not, you could simply store the Matlab-computed coefficients in a file and use these in your Python application

Comment: Indeed, that's the approach that I've wound up taking.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages offers higher accuracy data types.
For instance, on Python, you may use the [BigFloat](https://github.com/mdickinson/bigfloat) package.
There is always enough bits you can throw at it and get something working.

Yet a better approach is to use a different approach.
Since you're after a polynomial like model, you could use [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to get similar results with better numerical properties.
The trick here will be tweaking the ratio between $ \boldsymbol{Q} $ and $ \boldsymbol{R} $ to have similar results.

With some tweaking and hyper parameters grid search you will be able to easily do so.

**Remark**: If you share some signals we can try to implement the approach.